# Two servlets in xml with spring mvc in netbeans

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm practicing how to include ajax in spring-mvc with an example that I took from Internet but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is that I'm not able to run two servlets in the same xml but i don't know how to solve it.

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controladores.JsonServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JsonServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my jsp code with javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX in Servlet using JQuery and JSON</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#sports').change(function(event) {
        var sports = $("select#sports").val();
        $.get('JsonServlet', {
                sportsName : sports
        }, function(response) {

        var select = $('#player');
        select.find('option').remove();
          $.each($(foo), function(index, value) {
          $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
      });
        });
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>AJAX in Servlet using JQuery and JSON</h3>
        Select Favorite Sports:
        <select id="sports">
                <option>Select Sports</option>
                <option value="Football">Football</option>
                <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
        </select>
        <br /> <br /> 
        Select Favorite Player:
        <select id="player">
                <option>Select Player</option>
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public class JsonServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                String sportsName = request.getParameter("sportsName");
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                String json = null;

                if (sportsName.equals("Football")) {
                        list.add("Lionel Messi");
                        list.add("Cristiano Ronaldo");
                        list.add("David Beckham");
                        list.add("Diego Maradona");
                } else if (sportsName.equals("Cricket")) {
                        list.add("Sourav Ganguly");
                        list.add("Sachin Tendulkar");
                        list.add("Lance Klusener");
                        list.add("Michael Bevan");
                } else if (sportsName.equals("Select Sports")) {
                        list.add("Select Player");
                }

                json = new Gson().toJson(list);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
}
```

When I try to put only the JsonServlet appears this error: invalid path was requested.

And when I try to run the two servlets at the same time the application never goes through the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using spring dispatcherServlet, but write the raw servlet by yourself?

Comment: Because i'm using spring dispatcher servlet to control other controllers.